# Join two tables with using date, id, name order by datestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

guys i need two join below two table together and make it to 1 but , i dont care about index or other primary key , i treat timestamp as primary key , join it , and make it two order by sql query , i tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM paymentdetails,saletrack
WHERE saletrack.Date = paymentdetails.Date
```

but it returns zero row

Comment: ![table two][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XeXlF.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aFZnx.png

Comment: are there rows with same timestamp between the two tables?

Comment: You don't have any timestamps that match.  A timestamp seems like a poor choice for a primary key here.

Comment: i dont wanna acces any data using time stamp but just to show all transactions (billed and payed ) together on a html table

Comment: please take look images i comment above

Comment: You need to 'JOIN' the two tables on the .Date

Comment: @Einar He did - he's just using an archaic `Join` syntax that was deprecated over 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want `UNION` instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Date 
FROM paymentdetails
UNION  ALL
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Date
FROM saletrack
ORDER BY Date
```

Since you have different fields in the two tables you'll need to either pick only those that are in both tables, or add in `NULL` fields, like if you wanted to include the `Amountofpaying` field:

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Date
      ,Amountofpaying
FROM paymentdetails
UNION  ALL
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Date
     ,NULL AS Amountofpaying
FROM saletrack
```

Note: `UNION  ALL` will bring back every record, while `UNION` will exclude duplicate rows.

Comment: but how it can be ordered using date from both tables ?, im getting confused :'(

Comment: @user3704631 Just add `ORDER BY Date` to the end, see update.